# Script for printing out file names and their number of appearance starting from a given folder

Tags: bash

I need to write a shell script, which starts with a given folder name as an argument will print out the names of folder and files in it and how many times does each name appear in the given folder.
*edit* I need to check only their names, without taking into consideration the file extensions.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
folder="$1"
for f in "$folder"
do
  echo "$f"
done
```

And I would expect to see something like this (if i have 3 files with the same name and different extension like x.html, x.css, x.sh and so on, in a directory called dir)

```
x
3 times
```

after executing the script with dir (the name of the directory) as a parameter.

Comment: A file with a given name can only appear ones in a folder. The system cannot make any distinction between two files with the same name. Imagine `/home/user/foo` and `/home/user/foo` are two different files. How will you differentiate?

Comment: @kvantour I think OP already knows that, he wants to count filenames irrespective of their paths.

Comment: @oguzismail exactly,  i actually don't need to take into consideration their paths

Comment: @oguzismail your solution is almost what i'm looking for, but let's say i have two files: "xyz.sh" and "xyz.txt". I just have to print out "2 xyz", because i actually need to check only their names, without taking into consideration the file extensions

Comment: Updating the question to add new requirements after you have received several answers is not really a good idea. Clarifying what exactly you want is fine, of course; but changing the expected output risks invalidating the answers you already received.

Comment: @tripleee I didn't want to add any new requirements, i just wanted to clarify the question. That's why i updated the output i was expecting, because i saw it was confusing. It's one of my first question, maybe i didn't respect the "patterns", i'm sorry..

Comment: No problem; just try to take care to collect your requirements up front in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find` command already does most of this for you.

```
find . -printf "%f\n" |
sort | uniq -c
```

This will not work correctly if you have files whose names contain a newline.

If your `find` doesn't support `-printf`, maybe try

```
find . -exec basename {} \; |
sort | uniq -c
```

To restrict to just file names or directory names, add `-type f` or `-type d`, respectively, before the action (`-exec` or `-printf`).

If you genuinely want to remove extensions, try

```
find .... whatever ... |
sed 's%\.[^./]*$%%' |
sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n' array=($(ls))
iter=0;
for file in ${array[*]}; do
    filename=$(basename -- "$file")
    extension="${filename##*.}"
    filename="${filename%.*}"
    filenamearray[$iter]=$filename
    iter=$((iter+1))
done 

for filename in ${filenamearray[@]}; do
echo $filename;
grep -o $filename <<< "${filenamearray[@]}" | wc -l
done
```

Comment: This has incorrect quoting; you want `"${filenamearray[@]}"` with `@` and double quotes to correctly cope with file names which contain whitespace or other shell metacharacters.

Comment: Also, [don't parse `ls` output](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); and the repeated `grep` over the same set of lines is rather inefficient and inelegant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with find and awk :

```
find . -type f -print0 |
awk '
  BEGIN {
    FS="/"
    RS="\0"
  }
  {
    k = split( $NF , b , "." )
    if ( k > 1 )
      sub ( "."b[k] , "" , $NF )
    a[$NF]++
  }
  END {
    for ( i in a ) {
      j = a[i]>1 ? "s" : ""
      print i
      print a[i] " time" j
  }
}'
```